# DNS Token mismatch; email DNS setup Failure; what should be fixed?

Tags: email, dns

I'm trying to set up DNS for an email service that is hosted by a third party, and my DNS is hosted by digitalocean.
The propagation as checked by https://www.whatsmydns.net is returning Error: Token mismatch for all record types for the_domain.com

This is the domain file, what should I explore to fix it?

```
$ORIGIN the_domain.com.
$TTL 1800
the_domain.com. IN SOA ns1.digitalocean.com. hostmaster.the_domain.com. 1477796005 10800 3600 604800 1800
the_domain.com. 1800 IN NS ns1.digitalocean.com.
the_domain.com. 1800 IN NS ns2.digitalocean.com.
the_domain.com. 1800 IN NS ns3.digitalocean.com.
the_domain.com. 1800 IN A 104.131.137.128
the_domain.com. 1800 IN MX 100 us2.mx3.mailhostbox.com.
the_domain.com. 1800 IN MX 100 us2.mx1.mailhostbox.com.
the_domain.com. 1800 IN MX 100 us2.mx2.mailhostbox.com.
pop.the_domain.com. 1800 IN CNAME us2.pop.mailhostbox.com.
smtp.the_domain.com. 1800 IN CNAME us2.smtp.mailhostbox.com.
dav.the_domain.com. 1800 IN CNAME us2.dav.mailhostbox.com.
webmail.the_domain.com. 1800 IN CNAME us3.webmail.mailhostbox.com.
imap.the_domain.com. 1800 IN CNAME us2.imap.mailhostbox.com.
the_domain.com.the_domain.com. 1800 IN TXT "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.mailhostbox.com"
20150311._domainkey.the_domain.com.the_domain.com. 1800 IN TXT "v=DKIM1; g=*; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCDl+v04ZOpA1ZvAhP1lqugRETH4pSEvoQVyt9dPZ8IlhUNKGROC/tJqcbC+rSv/dbC4tCUA1tcoLL8AzuS41Gmp4ZwzHSmAa5i/iHCFzubPFWxPXUmWGYZayyRdzIdUTD3IEQaClNEAhDWcTm1kSUA1vr7VJTyKzfbnDWs+10WwwIDAQAB"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not an error with your DNS records, it is due to your browser visit being so long that the token the site sent to you initially times out, if you refresh the page that should fix the issue and you can continue to use it as before.

So just be wary that if you leave this website in an open tab for a while, you will need to refresh the page, this fixed the problem for me when I had this appear as I due to leaving it open for a few hours.

This problem also mentioned in https://serverfault.com/a/769330/396271

Comment: Yep, refreshed the page I had running overnight and it resolved my issue. You saved me a lot of frustration.